# Всем привет. Объясните пожалуйста, почему при вызове метода Print переменной ac типа А с ссылкой на C производится вызов метода из класса B, а не А?

Tags: c#, наследование, virtual, override, new

```
namespace ClassInterfaceDelegate
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A ac = new C();
            Console.WriteLine(ac.Print());
        }
    }

    public abstract class A
    {
        public virtual string Print() { return "A"; }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public override string Print() { return "B"; }
    }

    public class C : B
    {
        public new string Print() { return "C"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сначала Вы объясните, почему должен вызываться метод из `А`.

Comment: Ну насколько я понимаю, мы создаем переменную типа А и присваеваем ей ссылку на объект типа С. Но так как в классе С мы использовали new, а не override, то при создании экземпляра C никакая таблица с виртуальными методами не создается и поэтому метод Print() должен вызываться из класса А. Мое предположение, что вызывается именно реализация класса B из-за того, что класс В наследует А и там переопределяет метод Print(), а класс С уже наследует B и поэтому вызывается переопределенный метод. Если не так, то поправьте пожалуйста

Comment: "то при создании экземпляра C никакая таблица с виртуальными методами не создается" - неправильно. `C` является `A` и `B`.

Comment: т е если я правильно вас понял, то из-за данной иерархии классов (A->B->C) переменная типа A с ссылкой на C вызовет последнюю переопределенную реализацию метода Print()?